# XPath getting all information in tag X except the information in tag Y

Tags: xpath

In the code below, how do I grab all the information in class='pageHeading' using Xpath without grabbing whatever data is in the `<span>` tags?

The information I am after is simply: 'Shiny Hair Accessories'

This is what I have tried so far:

```
//*[@class='pageHeading' | //*[not(contains(@class, 'smallText'))]
//*[@class='pageHeading' and //*[not(contains(@class, 'smallText'))]
```

This is the code I am working on:

```
<td class="pageHeading" valign="top">
    Shiny Hair Accessories
   <br>
   <span class="smallText">[10672]</span>
   <br>
    <span class="smallText">UPC no. : 817953901653672</span>
</td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. The text() function got the first layer of text belonging to the element with the class 'pageHeading' while ignoring the span tags, like I needed.

```
//td[@class = 'pageHeading']/text()
```